# How do you manage your own comments on a foreign codebase?

Tags: coding-style, version-control

A common scenario I have is this:

I download a new codebase. In order to have me understand the code, I need to litter it with my own comments about what each section of code does.

It seems inappropriate to then push these messy comments back upstream.

So now I have a problem: my own codebase has a bunch of my own notes / comments, but I don't want to share them upstream with others.

I vaguely researched that maybe I can setup something to remove only certain types of my own comments each time I push, but I don't have a clear resource on the best way to set this up.

Comment: something like this? :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1bnNdEx9ig

Comment: You could always keep your comments in a separate (private) branch, and switch to that when you're doing code-analysis, then cherry-pick your actual changes back to the regular branch when you want to push something upstream.

Comment: Sure I can do this. But when I push to the regular branch, I want to automatically delete all my comments (or maybe comments identified by some prefix/header). how to do that?

Comment: Dunno about automatic ways, but I personally have a habit of putting always starting my temporary-for-debugging `printf()` lines in column 0, so that I can do a recursive grep/sed on the pattern `^printf` to quickly remove them all when I'm done debugging.  Perhaps you could do something similar for your comments.

Comment: If you require code comments to clarify the code, you should ideally talk with your team about readability of the code. With better naming of functions, classes, variables, code should be understandable

Comment: @Tvde1 yes. Good comments are nice, but _code that doesn't need comments_ is better.

Comment: Suggestion: write your own comments, not directly in the code base, but on a separate document. Then, clean up that document, polish it a bit, give it title "An introduction to our codebase", and commit it to the repo. The next new user to the codebase will thank you for it.

Comment: write a script that goes through the files of the commit list, remove all instances of the comments, then move them into another file with a line number beside it, and use a heading thats easy to parse for the file association, have the same script run one of two ways, puts the comments in, and takes them out. then before you make a pull request or push it for a code review you can remove you stuff. this is also a pretty simple computer science task at the end of the day.

Comment: You might mention "git diff > diffs.txt ; git reset --hard" to extract the changes and put them into a file, then remove them from the code; and "git apply" to get it back. Or "git stash" <-> "git stash pop". OP does not specify `git`, but other systems probably have similar commands.

Answer (score 49):

Simply get into the habit of writing *good* comments - short, neutral, objective and non-redundant information about *why* a bit of code is doing what it's doing - and then the authors will probably be happy to have them. Plus, the habit transfers to your own projects: everybody wins.

Comment: non-redundant is quite subjective though. A newcomer to a repo will be greatly guided by some comments, which people familiar with the repo might find redundant

Comment: @user3180 I'm pretty sure that wasn't what was intended by redundant. Unless the repo owners are openly hostile to external contributors, they wouldn't consider such comments redundant.

What was meant (I think) is the more common and amateur mistake of writing things like `index++; // increment index` - it looks stupid in this context, but it happens all too often, believe me.

Comment: Any piece of code that is not clear to a newcomer should be commented on. Don't comment on the mechanics. How a code works can be understood from reading the code. Comment on why the code is there and what it is supposed to do.

Comment: This. If the comment helps OP structure their own thoughts, then it will help everybody else too. While I know many devs who never write a single line of comments anywhere, I have never seen one who actively removes (good) comments.

Comment: An example of comments for newcomers but not experts are explanations of concepts from heavy APIs, such as Vulkan or Direct3D.

Comment: @PabloH I hope it's just the link and not multiple paragraphs. If I come across some Python module, I don't need someone to copy the entire guide to the module. Just stick the URL in there as a comment so I can quickly find it.

Comment: a little refactoring to make the intent of the code more self explanatory whenever possible is nice as well. a lot of comments can be eliminated by extracting a well named method. Remember that comments need to be maintained too, and that an out of date comment is often worse than no comment at all.

Comment: The strategy we use is to make sure that variable names are clear and functions have a very defined purpose with a name that matches. For public methods we also enforce summary text. Stand alone comments are only ever needed to explain why something was done the way it was done. Usually weird business rules. The rest can be worked out by just reading.

Comment: Assuming the code is written well, the only comments should really be about "why" something was implemented like this rather than "what" the code is doing. A newbie wouldn't have that context and almost all of their comments are going to be cruft.

Comment: @AnoE Strongly disagree, ordering your own thoughts is taking notes _for yourself_. Writing good comments is explaining _to others_, which is not going to happen by default.

Comment: @PasserBy, I'm happy to agree to disagree. If I have the choice of 20 lines of code with no comments and maybe not even blank lines inbetween to guide the eyes somewhat -vs- the same code with a few short one-line comments (like section titles in a book), I'll take the latter any day. Obviously I do not mean random rambling - the comments should obviously be correct and not totally superfluous (i.e. not simply reword the next line of code in human language)...

Comment: This will really make history of changes harder to follow, same way the bulk commiting whitespace fixes does.

Comment: @AnoE Those "section titles" comments often strongly imply that the single responsibility principle is being violated of the method (or that it works on different abstraction levels at the same time). In which case refactoring it into separate methods is a prudent choice (those comments usually are a great starter for a good method name too).

Comment: you are never more confused about a code base then when you first get into it, which, puts you in the best headspace to document it

Comment: @Voo, all true and well, for a code base you are familiar with or responsible for. When picking up existing code, especially older, convoluted or larger code bases, especially in languages that are not necessarily OOP through-and-through, dropping your initial comments in a well-structured way is what I'm talking about. Compare to i.e. structured note-taking (Obsidian etc.) or bullet-point task management instead of just scribbling something on a sticky.

Answer (score 19):

Use a junk drawer.

It is perfectly ok to mess with code locally and never push your changes to anyone else. I’ve done this for years.

There is nothing special about code that means you can’t keep drafts of changes you know you can never publish.

The trick is being sure you never accidentally publish this work. //TODO markers can help with that.

I read code with my fingers. I transform it and write comments that only I would ever understand. I don’t show this to others. I use this work to figure out what I should show others.

But the last thing you should do is “maintain” the junk drawer. Everything sent here is meant to die here. That frees you. Use this as stepping stone on the way to code that you can show others.

Remember, in 6 months time you’ll be as clueless as others. So don’t forget that creating truly readable code helps you too.

In short, not everything you write must be ready for the world. It’s ok to have your own notes that only make sense to you.

Comment: How do we automate this though? For example, perhaps I could pre-pend all my comments I don't want uploaded with some prefix, then I have a script that strips these comments every time I push upstream.

Comment: //TODO: remove.

Comment: I need some script to automatically strip comments with //TODO: remove

Comment: Was thinking more along the lines of making your push fail when that is detected.

Comment: I often make selective commits of things I want to remove later, like debug `printf`s, then when the branch is otherwise ready for merging, I remove those commits. This normally gives me a few conflicts to resolve, but those are trivial.

Answer (score 11):

(All assuming you're using git; most of this should have parallels in any other reputable modern VCS)

I once wrote a [git pre-commit hook](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks) to fail if it found the text `NO-COMMIT` in the modified files. That way, I could comment `// NO-COMMIT blah` and be assured that I wouldn't accidentally commit that comment, and I could also mark files that I felt like I might forget I needed to come back to and clean up.

Writing such a thing to actually remove those comments would be harder, and also it's not good practice for hooks to be modifying code (yes, even linter hooks--they should fail the commit, not modify your commit).

If you're using a GUI tool that makes it easy to commit only certain lines, then the commit hook could be valuable in doing what you're describing. Otherwise, this is quite a pain to do from the command line and I would recommend a different flow, such as keeping notes in separate files. You can set up a local `.gitignore` to filter out files of a particular pattern, such as `**.mynotes.*`, and then put notes for `foo.js` in `foo.mynotes.txt`.

Comment: I disagree with the claim that GUIs are necessary to make staging hunks easier (it’s easier in Vim with Pathogen than with the interactive flags), but I’m not sure if this subtlety is worth editing for.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble if something is easier in Vim, then it's hard.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble isn't [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) a package manager, which, in itself, has nothing to do with git? gitsigns or Fugitive.vim allow to stage hunks, for example. But as much as I love vim, the process of `git add -i` is much smoother with vscode + gitgraph than in any vim plugin I've tried.

Comment: @EricDuminil yikes, I did mean Fugitive above

Answer (score 6):

Many modern IDEs have a concept of bookmarks or similar, where you can annotate code / lines with extra information without altering the source code.

That being said, if the codebase you downloaded is lacking documentation/comments to such a level that you had to add your own, then it seems natural that probably some of those comments do in fact belong in that codebase.

On a different perspective, as @kilian-foth already mentioned, it's great to observe a few points when it comes to this subject:

1. code should be self-documenting - prefer descriptive names over short variables (`rowIndex` instead of `x`, `i`, `n`... or `getUser()` instead of `user()`)
2. similarly, if at all possible, avoid writing comments explaining what should have been clear in code - ie, prefer fixing the code over commenting it
3. prefer commenting on why instead of what - many badly written comments simply describe what the code is doing (which is typically visible) as opposed to why that is not (typically not visible/obvious)

Back to the original question, if you're using version control, consider making a branch with just your comments - this allows you to "toggle" your changes just by switching branches (and updating/rebasing your branch in case of upstream changes)

Answer (score 3):

`git` is your friend whenever you need to maintain private additions to a codebase. Independent of whether it's a good idea to maintain such private additions in the first place. I would handle it like this:

1. Create a new branch `private-additions` and check it out.
2. Add any comments and other private things you want and commit them to `private-additions`.
3. If you ever create something you do want to publish, commit it to `master` or some other feature branch that does not know anything about your `private-additions` branch. This can easily be published in the normal way.
4. Whenever you fetch new changes from upstream, simply merge them into your `private-additions` branch or rebase it onto the upstream `master`. This allows you to look at the new code with your old additional comments.

Since the changes on `private-additions` are never merged into `master`, you retain a pristine view of the upstream repository. However, whenever you checkout your `private-additions` you get your own commented view of things.

Only downside is, that it can get a bit messy to peel things apart should you accidentally commit changes for publication to your `private-additions` branch or the other way round. Nothing that can't be sorted out with `git rebase -i`, but something that should be avoided nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

I developed an own annotation system for comments where I start certain "temporary" comments with a specific word:

```
// TODO: Add a proper rating algorithm 
ratingScore = 1.0f;

// NOTE: Factors I should take into account: Proximity, difficulty, risk, reward

// DEBUG:
Debug.Log(ratingScore);
```

It's easy to scan source files for such comments, both visually and tool-assisted.